# How to collect custom information from users and show then in custom pages?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am building clothing store.
And want to collect measurements from the users through a form fields / custom fields.
Does shopify theming provide that kind functionality/options? 
If so can I show those collected info in other pages rather then check out?

Or should I use a different approach ? Like a client side solution. Collect data with js then  save it in local storage to show in cart/product pages.
Then post that data as a contact form.

Thank you for your time and suggestions. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to collect this information per product or do you want to store it with a customer profile to use later?

If it is just per product you can use this...
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/features/get-customization-information-for-products

If you're trying to collect it for a customer and store it on their profile you could do it through this...
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/forms/get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form

Comment: yes, I do want to store that with a customer profile, and they can add multiple measurements and use one to order clothes. Which seems not possible

Comment: I believe you could to do it but it would be very hacky... In the customer registration form you could have a button that dynamically adds fields for a new set of measurements. Before form submit you could parse the data into json format and store in an array in a text field on their profile. Then call that array later on the product page. Would be a very hacky way around it though and not sure if it will create the best user experience.